# Pyspark performance: dataframe.collect() is very slow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I try to make a collect on a dataframe it seems to take too long.

I want to collect data from a dataframe to transform it into a dictionary and insert it into documentdb. But the performance seems to be very slow when the day_rows.collect() is performed

```
day_rows = self._sc.sql("select * from table")

rows_collect = []

if day_rows.count():
    rows_collect = day_rows.collect()

results = map(lambda row: row.asDict(), rows_collect)
```

Why is the performance slow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cache your dataframe, before .collect().
This will increase the performance by magnitudes.

df.persist() or df.cache()

Once you are done with the usage, you can always unpersist.

Comment: So before performing df.collect () should I use df.cache ()?

for example

`day_rows.cache ()
day_rows.collect ()`

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I mean. But remember that caching itself takes some time so essentially you are avoiding the sql to run again  and consuming your memory for faster operations on dataframe such a . collect () any . show etc..

Comment: @MradulDwivedi, could you explain why this works? Caching is done to prevent multiple execution of the DAG / broke the lineage into parts, isn't it?

Comment: @makewithplus, you can read this for more details. Explains pretty much why and how it works. https://towardsdatascience.com/apache-spark-caching-603154173c48

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is taking so long for you is because you are also querying a data set which is activating when you call the collect.

```
day_rows = self._sc.sql("select * from table)
```

If you were just calling a collect instead of collecting from a query on another RDD, it would not be taking as long.

You can find more detail (and a similar, not similar enough to be duplicated, question) from my previous answer, here: [Why RDD calculating count take so much time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57033077/why-rdd-calculating-count-take-so-much-time/57040142#57040142)

Comment: So to be more performant should I do something similar to this?

day_rows = self._sc.sql ("select * from table).collect ()