# When does Spark dataframe pull the data from source

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark dataframes and a little bit confused on its working. I had 2 similar piece of codes which is taking different amount of time to complete. Any explanation for these would be really helpful:

```py
selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM items limit 1"
items_df = spark_session.sql(selectQuery)  # completes in ~4 seconds
data_collect = items_df.collect()  # completes in ~50 seconds

selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY ingest_date limit 1"
items_df = spark_session.sql(selectQuery)  # completes in ~4 seconds
data_collect = items_df.collect()  # completes in ~20 minutes
```

My thought process over here was that, `spark_session.sql(selectQuery)` is the actual code that pulls data from Source and puts it in the application memory in the form of dataframe. Then `collect()` simply converts that dataframe into a python list.

But clearly, I see that `collect()` depends on the query as well.

PS: I saw an answer in this thread where a person mentions that `collect()` activates the actual query execution. I do not quite understand this.
[Pyspark performance: dataframe.collect() is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57152706/pyspark-performance-dataframe-collect-is-very-slow?rq=1)

Comment: Spark does not load/process data until an action is called. collect(), show() are some of actions that trigger the actual execution. this process is called lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a dataframe, you can apply two kind of methods : Transformations and Actions.

Transformations are lazy, it means they are not executed right away. Transformations are for example : `withColumn`, `where`, `select` ... A transformation always return a dataframe. When executed, Spark just checks if they are valid: for exemple, `withColumn` is a transformation, and when you apply it to your dataframe, the validity of your request is checked directly but not executed :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.range(10)

df.withColumn("id_2", F.col("id") * 2) # This one is OK
df.withColumn("id_2", F.col("foo") * 2) # This one will fail because foo does not exist
```

Actions are the method that will execute all the transformations that have been stacked. Actions are, for example, `count`, `collect`, `show`.
At the moment you apply an action, Spark will retrieve the data where it is stored, apply all the transformation you asked previously, and return a result depending on the action you asked (a list if it is a collect, a number if you made a count)

---

In you case, the creation of the dataframe is a transformation. It is lazy, just the validity will be checked. That is why both queries takes approx the same amount of time.

But when collecting, that's the moment when spark will retrieve all the data. So depending on the amount of data in the tables (and the number of transformations you asked) it will take more or less time to complete.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation @steven.